# Angular javascript Primeng growl won't wrap text to next line

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, primeng

In Angular/Javascript, I am trying to get the text in growl to wrap using primeng 4.0.1.  Specifically, I'm putting a file path into the growl, and it's such a long file path that it doesn't fit on one line. I just want it to wrap to the next line, but it won't do that.

I have tried a number of things.  First, I tried modifying the css.  Second, I tried creating a div to hold the growl and creating a style class for that div, setting word-wrap to bread-word and overflow-wrap to break-word.

Originally, I had no css for the growl.  The css  I added (below) will change the color successfully, but it seems word-wrap and overflow-wrap do not work as they should.

```
/deep/.ui-growl-message {
    float: left;
    color: purple;
    word-wrap:break-word !important;
    overflow-wrap: break-word !important;

}
```

html looks like this:

```
<p-growl [(value)]="msgs" sticky="false"></p-growl>
```

Sorry if this is a novice question - I don't really do UI dev.

Symptom is attached for reference.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried `white-space: normal`?

Comment: @Enve Sorry for the delay getting back to you - no code access over the weekend.  I tried the white-space: normal attribute just now, but it does not appear to have any effect.

Comment: In that case I have no idea what the cause might be. If you could share some more code after Angular rendering that would be helpful. Just inspect element in your browser and copy relevant HTML/CSS

Answer (score 1):

Got it.  The key to making it work was also specifying the width like so:

```
/deep/.ui-growl-message {
    float: left;
    color: purple;
    word-wrap:break-word !important;
    overflow-wrap: break-word !important;
    width: 85%;
}
```